# Getting Type Mismatch error in function as parameter in scala

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming

I am facing some issues of type mismatch in scala when I am calling the `in_shuffle` method from `n_shuffle` by passing a function as a parameter.

```
  def in_shuffle[T](original: List[T], restrict_till:Int= -1):List[T]={

    require(original.size % 2 == 0, "In shuffle requires even number of elements")
    def shuffle(t: (List[T], List[T])): List[T] =
      t._2 zip t._1 flatMap { case (a, b) => List(a, b) }

    def midpoint(l: List[T]): Int = l.size / 2

    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(current: List[T], restrict_till:Int, count:Int=0): List[T] = {
      if (original == current || restrict_till == count) current
      else{
        val mid         = midpoint(current)
        val shuffled_ls = shuffle(current.splitAt(mid))
        loop(shuffled_ls, restrict_till, count+1)
      }
    }
    loop(shuffle(original.splitAt(midpoint(original))), restrict_till, 1)
  }
```

```
def n_shuffle[T](f: (List[T], Int) => List[T], list:List[T], n:Int):List[T]={
  println("Inside Sub-function")
  f(list, n)
}
```

Here is how i'm calling `n_shuffle` in `main` 
`print( n_shuffle(in_shuffle, (1 to 8).toList, 2) )`

Error I am getting is

```
Error:(161, 22) type mismatch;
 found   : (List[Nothing], Int) => List[Nothing]
 required: (List[Int], Int) => List[Int]
    print( n_shuffle(in_shuffle, (1 to 8).toList, 2) )
```

Any help will highly be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `in_shuffle` is working perfectly fine. But facing issues only when I call the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try multiple parameter lists to aid type inference

```
def n_shuffle[T](list: List[T], n: Int)(f: (List[T], Int) => List[T]): List[T]
n_shuffle((1 to 8).toList, 2)(in_shuffle)
```

or provide explicit type annotation

```
n_shuffle(in_shuffle[Int], (1 to 8).toList, 2)
n_shuffle[Int](in_shuffle, (1 to 8).toList, 2)
```

The reason compiler is unable to infer type of the first parameter in

```
def n_shuffle[T](f: (List[T], Int) => List[T], list: List[T], n: Int)
```

is because it would get it from `(1 to 8).toList` however that is the second argument.

Comment: Got you. But @Mario Isn't it the complex method to pass the function as a parameter???

Comment: It would be more usual to put the function argument by itself so `def n_shuffle[T](list: List[T], n: Int)(f: (List[T], Int) => List[T])` to make the call look better when using a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the inference in this case does not work as expected. Forcing the type in in_shuffle[Int] method did the trick.

Try this instead.

```
print(n_shuffle(in_shuffle[Int], (1 to 8).toList, 2))
```